# What do I do with all the logic in my django views when converting my project to django rest api with reactJS?

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I created a web app all in django. I am now wanting to practice using reactJS on the front end, therefore it seems I need to make my django app an api end point to send and receive json data from reactJS.  Now, my understanding is the api views are all very simple just to post and get data. My question is, where do my normal views go? I'd assume these views and logic all now has to go in reactJS front end with JS?

For example, one view in my current django app is what to do after user submits a youtube channel in a form. The view goes through all the logic (ie if it exists and is registered, show all the related comments, if the channel exists but not registered, register and save in db, if doesn't exist on youtube notify and stay on current page.

This logic has to be now put on front end if I switch to using django rest api? I can't get my head around this.

Thanks!

Comment: The logic will remain on django. React only send and receive data to/ from the api.

Comment: Each 'feature' (show related comments, check if channel exists, register channel) should be api calls from your react app